# A smooth function whose derivatives satisfy smallness condition near a point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $f\in C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\right)$. Suppose that, for $n\geq 1$, we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f^{\prime}(x)+a_{1}xf^{\prime\prime}(x)+...+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}f^{(n)}(x)}{x^n}$$ 
exists, for a given sequence of reals $(a_{n})$.

I want to show that there does not exist a function $f$ that satisfies the countably many conditions above except for a function constant near $0$, and  functions of the form $f(x):=g(x^{n+1})$.

Is this true ? How prove it if true?

Comment: Is there supposed to be some sort of condition on $(a_n)$ or $g$? $-\cos$ would satisfy this relation for some particular sequence that you could recursively construct with the analytic extension of $g=\cos(\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I am afraid I don't follow though. $\lim_{x\rightarrow {0}^{+}} \frac{g^{\prime}(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\rightarrow {0}^{+}} \frac{\sin{\sqrt{x}}}{x\sqrt{x}}=+\infty$.

Comment: In fact, if $a_{n}=0$, then $f$ must be constant near $0$ because of the condition that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{x^n}$ exists for all $n\geq 1$, which means that $f^{\prime}$ must be identically zero near the origin.

Comment: If you define $f=-\cos$ and take $a_1=-1, a_2=0, a_3=1/3, a_4=0, a_5=-2/15, a_6=0, a_7=17/315, \cdots$  and continue to recursively define this sequence, you'll get a nonzero $f$.

Comment: Could you further explain, please ? I do not understand the sequence (cannot predict the next term(s))  and I do not know what is going to happen to the numerator either. Thanks.

Comment: Also, a counterexample should be an $f$ not constant near the origin(equivalently an $f$ with a nonzero first derivative near the origin). Not a nonzero $f$.

Comment: Are you saying that, we can add a trigonometric term that makes the sum as small as we wish ?  a little too hard to buy..a rigorous proof is in order.

Comment: ... $\cos$ isn't constant on any open neighborhood of $0$. I don't know the general term for the sequence, but it's apparent that it can be continued indefinitely. I'm using the notation in your question.

Comment: The sequence you gave works. One may be able to prove the existence of this sequence rigorously by induction. What about the case when the coefficients are known ?